# Actual definitions of screen and virtual image

Tags: optics

As definition a virtual image cannot be caught in screen. But what is actually a screen? Because if we assume our eye as screen the image reflected by plane glass should not be sensed by us. But it is really not true.  So what is a screen which cannot capture virtual image?

Answer (score 3):

A screen is precisely what you'd expect it to be ─ a piece of paper, some cloth, a CCD sensor, a human retina, you name it. When we say that real images can be caught on a screen, we mean that if you put the screen at the precise location of the image, then it will act like if it was a real object; when we say that virtual images cannot be caught on a screen, we mean that if you put a screen at the location of the image, then nothing will happen.

There are two requirements on the screen in this regard:

- It **must** be placed at the precise location where the virtual image is located.
- It **cannot** come coupled with additional optics, i.e. it cannot involve lenses of any kind.

The human eye does not satisfy either of those requirements.

Comment: What  is meant by the precise location of virtual image?

Comment: The location at which the virtual image appears. That means that you'd need to put your retina *at* the image, not at some point far away, and not with e.g. your iris at the image. It also means that you'd need to take away your eye's iris, lens, and vitreous humour.

Answer (score 2):

Your base definition is correct, however projection an image isn't the same as seeing an image:
[image: diagram]

the virtual image can not be projected onto a screen because there are no real photons - there are no photons inside the mirror, hence it cannot be projected, yet you can see it